# Textbox gridview in asp:asyncpostbacktrigger with updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel

I have a textbox in a gridview templatefield and I want to handle its TextChanged event. The problem is using the UpdatePanel trigger I get the following message?

> A control with ID 'txtQtd' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'

How can I incorporate this control into updatepanel?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Origin" ItemStyle-Width="8%" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Destiny" ItemStyle-Width="8%"/>
      <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtQtd" AutoPostBack="true"  OnTextChanged="txtQtd_TextChanged" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
       </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Factor" ItemStyle-Width="8%" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

</ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtQtd" EventName="TextChanged"  />

    </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is put an invisible button that calls the txtQtd_TextChanged method from javascript, that is, you put the onchange property inside the textbox and when this is executed you will call the button with document.getElementById (MainContent_btn).click();

It's just an idea